# Two name combination using for loop in java

Tags: java

What I want is that asks the user to enter three (3) first names then display the following:
All the possible two-name combinations. 
 For example I will input Mike Tyler Bryle

> Mike Tyler 
>  Mike Bryle 
>  Tyler Mike 
>  Tyler Bryle 
>  Bryle Mike 
>  Bryle Tyler

Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Javacomprog{
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //GET THE NAME FIRST
       String name_1, name_2, name_3;
       String prints =" ";
       //STORING THE 3 NAMES
       String[] a_names = new String[3];
       //COMBINATION NAME
       String[] c_names = new String[3];
       
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       
       //STORE IN ARRAY THE USER INPUT NAMES
       System.out.println("Enter three first names:");
       for(int i = 0; i < a_names.length; i++){
           a_names[i] = sc.nextLine();
       }
       // STORE THE NAME COMBINATION
       for(int j = 0; j < a_names.length; j++){

        int a = 0;
        
        //CHECK IF IT IS A REPEATED NAME USING EQUAL IGNORECASE
        if(a_names[a].equalsIgnoreCase(a_names[j]) == true){
         a++;
        }
         c_names[j] = a_names[a]+ " " + a_names[j];
   
    
       }
       //PRINT NAME COMBINATION
       for(int l = 0; l < c_names.length; l++){
        System.out.println(c_names[l] + " ");  
       }
       


    }
    
}
```

Can you explain how do I do the name combination using for loop thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the combinations using nested for loops based on how many combinations you want to find. In this case, you want pairs so two loops (an outer and inner) will be sufficient.

```
String[] names = {"Mike", "Tyler", "Bryle"};
List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < names.length - 1; i++) {
  for(int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
    combinations.add(names[i] + " " + names[j]);
    combinations.add(names[j] + " " + names[i]);
  }
}
for(String name : combinations)
  System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just print them instead of adding them to an arraylist.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yep, if they only plan to display the names and nothing more. I stored them in a collection mostly out of habit rather than necessity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can use two for-loops, both corresponding at the indice to have the same name.

- We compare `i == j` in the inner loop, these are the same names.
- If it is not equal than we will print the name.

Code:

```
String[] a_name = {"Max", " Moritz"};

 for (int i = 0; i < a_name.length ; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < a_name.length; j++) {
              if(i != j){
              System.out.println(a_name[i] + " " + a_name[j]);
            }
          }
       }
```

Comment: I'm comparing two integers and not strings

Comment: `!(i == j)` could simply be replaced by `i != j`.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. :)